# When is $2^{2n}-1$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to find the biggest prime number smaller than $10^{7}$ that can be written in the form $2^{2n}-1$, where $n$ is any real number. For example, I plugged in $1.5=n$ and found a prime number. I know I could use trial and error but I think there is an easier way.
I have been able to reduced the problem to $2^{n}-1$ and have tried to find a pattern but have been unsuccessful. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a hint on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow $n$ to be any real, you can express any prime $p$ this way.  You have 
$$2^{2n}-1=p\\2n=\log_2 (p+1)\\n=\frac 12(\log_2 (p+1))$$
so the largest prime less than $10^7$ is the one you want.

Comment: The largest such prime is $p_{664579}=9999991$ with $n\approx11.62674775\dots$

Answer (score 6):

If $n$ is any real, as Ross said above, $2^{2n}-1=p\iff n=\frac 12\log_2(p+1)$, and thus, any prime can be written that way. If you restrict $n$ to be an integer, the answer is, never, except $n=1$, as, $2^{2n}-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$, and if $2^n-1>1$, this object is never a prime.